# Date Range search - tSQL using nvarchar

Tags: t-sql, date-range

Apologies for not using the correct type (date). Poor choice using `nvarchar`, but I cannot convert at this stage.

To the question:

I want to be able to search for data in a certain date range, e.g., 10.01.16 -> 19.02.16

However, it seems to bring back only the first two digits worth of data, so everything between 10 and 19 regardless of month and year.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT ID, Day, Date FROM oneHr$
WHERE date >= CONVERT(NVARCHAR, '10.01.16', 4)
AND date <= CONVERT(NVARCHAR , '19.02.16', 4)
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Any ideas? Help very much appreciated and thanks in advance.

This is what is being returned:

```
ID   Day    Date
--------------------
943  fri    10.02.15
746  mon    10.02.16
234  tue    10.03.15
835  fri    10.04.15
988  tue    10.05.15
487  wed    11.01.16
343  wed    11.02.15
874  mon    12.01.16
663  thu    12.01.15
198  tue    12.02.15
775  wed    13.01.16
993  thu    14.01.15
375  fri    15.03.15
337  wed    16.12.15
784  tue    17.11.15
777  mon    18.08.15
252  thu    19.01.16
664  wed    19.02.15
```

*UPDATE*

So, I've changed Date to be of type datetime and all looking good. However, I'm trying to define a range rather than hard code it and it isn't working. Any ideas?

```
set @date1 = '2016-01-01 00:00:00' -- Date1 (start range)
set @date2 = '2016-01-10 00:00:00' -- Date2 (end range)

/* Not Working */
select * from oneHr$
where Date >= @date1
and Date <= @date2
order by ID

/* Working */
select * from oneHr$
where Date >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
and Date <= '2016-01-10 00:00:00'
order by ID
```

Comment: Resolved! It was getting late, I had not tidied up my tSQL script correctly. Therefore, convert to datetime and all works well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like this?

```
SELECT ID, Day, Date FROM oneHr$
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, date, 4) >= @Date1
AND CONVERT(DATE, date, 4) <= @Date2
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Then you won't have to convert your inputs to nvarchar at all.

Comment: JUst so the OP is clear, the reason why waht he is doing is not working is that nvarchar uses a string sort to order and thus to use in a between type of query as well.  So in a string sort '11.01.05' is between '10.01.16' and '19.02.16'  This is the solution without changing schema but is going to be very expensive performance-wise if this is a large table. Can you add a column that converts to real dates through a trigger on insert or update of your current column?

Comment: Thanks. So I have tried with query suggested above and I get the following errors - "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2098
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Date is of type nvarchar. I am thinking I will have to explore changing the schema to correct type. I do not have that much data (as of now), but in a year or two will be in excess of +1M rows.